# Identical LuceneNet search query returns different results on different servers

Tags: nhibernate, lucene.net

I am using two servers, a Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise and Windows 2008 R2 Standard.

Everything related to building the Lucene index and query is identical, but the search results are coming out incorrectly on the 2008 R2 Enterprise box. All of the assemblies are the same versions, everything about the code base is identical.

I am baffled as to why this might occur. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does each server builds its own index?

Comment: yes. i have an indexer program that runs on both servers to generate the local index.

Comment: try copying over the index from one server to the other and see if results still come back different, that will determine if your issue is at search or indexing time

Comment: I will do that. lets see what happens

Comment: I copied over the index from the working server. The search now runs correctly on the affected server. So if the problem is during indexing... then this appears to be the single call into NHivernate.Search that indexes the object. "session.Index(toIndex);".

Comment: Make sure the nhibernate configurations are the same on each machine, if yes then inspect your index with luke to find out the differences you have (http://code.google.com/p/luke/)

Comment: I found what the problem is. In the app.config, I forgot to specify the default analyzer on the affected machine. Therefore it was indexing with the StandardAnalyzer and later attempting to search using a custom analyzer. Your suggestion to copy the index was key to helping me figure this out quickly. How can I credit your response?

Answer (score 1):

When you encouter issues like this one with Lucene, and you are certain the input data is the same, it is usually caused because you do not use the same Analyzers for indexing and searching.

Double check your nhibernate configurations to make sure you Index and Search the data the same way on both servers.